# How to resolve NZEC error on codechef while inputting matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

As there is a pandemic my college is asking us to submit assignment via codechef and while submitting it shows NZEC: runtime error.(I use python) I'm sure it is while inputting the values and i can't seem to resolve it, please tell how can i change following lines of code to remove the error

```
dim_x,dim_y,num_nonZero = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
matrix = []
for x in range(num_nonZero):
    row = [int(z) for z in input().split()]
    matrix.append(Element(*row))

start_x,start_y = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

Where Element is a class with constructor as

```
def __init__(self,x,y,value=None,direction=0):
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common error is due to

> A program that is utilizing more memory space than the allocated memory for our program to run.

But I don't see how that can be a case in yours. It is also advisable to test your program using an offline interpreter on your computer to check that it matches your output with the specified outputs exactly.

I am inclined to think that they maybe caused by the numerous syntax errors you have,
`dim_x,dim_y,num_nonZero = [int(x) for x in input().split()]` and `start_x,start_y = [int(x) for x in input().split()]` and `matrix.append(Element(*row))`. These are all syntactically incorrect and if you run it on `idle` for example would throw runtime error.

Comment: i tried running it on online interpreter and no they are no syntax errors

Comment: Try offline, on your system. Use idle for example